# how to create a container without giving it a height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

have tried to wrapp the tabbarview with expanded but its not working.
I do not want to give the height as the items displayed there can be many.
I want the height to increase the number of items available to be scrolled.
The issue at hand is i do not want to add any height to that container.
Any help

this here is the code in the body where i have my tabbar

````
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Let the party begin!",
                            style: titleStyle1.copyWith(fontSize: 28.0),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                   SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => SlideInRight(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            child: Search(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                      height: 45.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: background,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                blurRadius: 5.0,
                                spreadRadius: 0.0)
                          ]),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Search...',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: grey),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      indicatorColor: authlink,
                      labelColor: authlink,
                      unselectedLabelColor: grey,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(text: "All"),
                        Tab(text: "Trending"),
                        Tab(text: "Live"),
                        Tab(text: "Happening Today"),
                      ]),
                  Container(
//without this height i get this problem

                    // height: 580.0,
                    child: new TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                child: buildAllComingEventList(),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: buildNearbyEventList(),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: moreConcerts(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: trendingConcerts(),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          child: getStories(),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: happeningTodayConcerts(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),```
````

Answer (score 1):

What if you change other way to layout your page:

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: //your button
          flexibleSpace: //your search bar
          bottom: //your tab bar
        ),
        body: // your tab view
      ),
```

Comment: A good idea,let me try it then get back to you